# Creating a driver to translate HID-USB requests into HCI packets

Tags: c++, bluetooth, windows-10, driver

So this may seem a little odd, but I'm rather limited by the hardware I have on hand.

I've got a device that consists of a TI CC2640R2 wired to a Silicon Labs CP2110 UART to USB-HID bridge. The basic premise of the device is to send Bluetooth HCI commands from the TI chip to the CP2110, which translates the UART data to an HID record, which can be read by application code on the host machine, and vice versa. What I'd like to do is to wire this device into the predefined HCI stack in Windows 10, so the desktop can use the device as a standard Bluetooth endpoint.

Normally, this wouldn't be a problem, as the device's USB chip would enumerate it as a Bluetooth device, which would cause the PnP manager in Windows to attach it to the system's Bluetooth stack. The HID device, however, complicates matters.

In order to make this work properly, I'd need to intercept HID records from the target device, unpack them, and forward them to the HCI stack so Windows Bluetooth would know what to do. I'd have to do the exact opposite going the other way - take an HCI command, package it into the appropriate HID record, and send the record to the target device.

I've managed to get the source code for the KMDF example of a Bluetooth Serial HCI Bus Driver, but I don't know the proper way to get the target device from the HID class driver, or if I'd need to do something with an HID minidriver to bridge the two driver stacks.

Is it possible to retrieve a pointer to an HID device from kernel mode, and if so, how would I go about doing that?

If not, and an HID minidriver is required to intercept and relay commands, what would be the best method of combining the HCI driver and the HID minidriver to allow the two to interoperate cleanly?

Comment: I do not think there is easy solution on driver kevel but why do not use WinUSB and BlueKitchen bluetooth driver?

Comment: Because BlueKitchen would not allow the Windows system to utilize the device, which is what I want. I could use the device from an application, but I can already do that by opening the device from usermode with the CP2110 interface DLL. Again, I have no need to use the device directly. What I want is for Windows to be able to use the device, which requires linking into the Windows Bluetooth stack.

Comment: Then probably IUSb filter driver can help. On one side the driver talk to yuor device as to HIDand on other side it represents your device as Bluetooth one. Similar to filter driver for 2in1 Bluetooth+WiFi cards in some Toshiba laptops